# Change font color while typing on OS X

Tags: macos, fonts

Is there a way to type in color on a Mac? Or is there an app that can do this?

For example, if I'm typing in a document or an email, I'd like to change the color.

Comment: What do you mean by "type color"?  The color of text in finder?  The color of text in a document?

Comment: @wizlog I mean if I am typing in a document or in any place that I would type something,  email,  etc.  By type I mean font.  As in typing words on a keyboard.

Comment: @Grahm OK, I get it, thank you for reiterating.

Comment: @Graham Would that not depend on the application/website you're typing in?

Comment: @fideli Not sure.  That was what I was wondering.  If I could type in any color anywhere that I would type something.  Sounds like it might make a good app if it does not exist.  Does it exist?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to type in color …

Yes.

[image]

In a Mail? Sure.

[image]

Those fields that support it (in *native* OS X apps like Pages, TextEdit, Numbers, etc.), will often map <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to the color picker window.

More generally, any app implementing `NSTextView` can [change the color](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of the text, and most often, this option is exposed to the user through a color picker.

Anywhere else, like "normal" text-only boxes, there's no such feature I know of, and it's unlikely you could just change the color there on the fly, because after all, they're just supposed to contain text. It is certainly possible to write applications with changeable color text fields, but I haven't seen one that actually lets you do that "live".